# html width height 100%

Tags: codeigniter, web, base-url

i have css like this

```
.home{        
    height:100%;
    width:100%; 
    font-size:20px;     
}
```

and i have html like this

```
<div class="home">
        <div style="text-align:center;padding-top:10%;height:45%;">first text here
        </div>
        <div style="padding-top:2%;height:33%;background:#0099FF;text-align:center;">second text here           
        </div>      
        </div>
```

but when i run this code in web browser,the height is not fit 100%, it display more than 100%
in css, i set home class : height 100% 
in html, i make 2 div.set style = 10%+45%+2%+33% = 90%

but when i run in web browser it more than 100% (i can scroll a mouse down)

i want 100% height, there is any

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers add their own padding. Try resetting the padding, margins globally

```
* {margin:0;padding:0;}
```

You may also want to add these in there along with padding and margin if support for IE7 is not required. It will make calculations a lot easier

```
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* <=iOS4, <= Android  2.3 */
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox 1+ */
      box-sizing: border-box; /* Chrome, IE8+, Opera, Safari 5.1*/
```

Comment: i have included * {margin:0;padding:0;} in my css. but it still same